# Sitecore rocks using fast query in query analyzer

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

Is it possible to use fast queries in the sitecore rocks query analyzer or is it only suitable to use normal queries? 
And if I can use fast queries, how can I use them?

I have tried:

```
query:fast:/sitecore/content/home//*[@@templateid='{8A59A5A0-D634-4713-B32C-B0272CCEF9B3}']

fast:/sitecore/content/home//*[@@templateid='{8A59A5A0-D634-4713-B32C-B0272CCEF9B3}']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, Sitecore Rocks Query Analyzer does not support fast queries.

This is because Sitecore Query is a pretty closed API and Rocks has to make significant hacks to extend it.

Sorry about this.